# When do geodesics reconverge?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, contact-geometry

Say I stand at the north pole and talk; in sufficiently frictionless conditions, one imagines that someone standing at the south pole could listen.

More generally, say $M$ is a compact Riemannian manifold, and $N$ is a compact submanifold.  I look at the geodesic flow leaving $N$ in all normal directions.  For most times $t$, these points form a hypersurface of codimension 1 in $M$.

> > When can it happen that, at some time $t$, all these geodesics meet in some locus of codimension $> 1$?

(I.e.: when can it happen that the front projection of the time $t > 0$ Reeb flow to a submanifold of the unit conormal bundle is codimension $>1$?)

Comment: There is a lot of classical material about this. Look for "Wiedersehensflaeche" (even in English) and for "focal point".

Comment: Also, you might want to look up the literature on isoparametric submanifolds of the $n$-sphere.

Comment: You might look at my summary paper: Summary of progress on the Blaschke conjecture: https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.1326.